# Connect to SQL Server requires CMD launched with explicit credentials

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

[Updated my query with more test Scenarios]

I'm running below VBS code in four scenarios.

**Connection string 1:** added "User ID=YYDOMAIN\YYAccount;Password=YYPassword;" and removed "Integrated Security=SSPI"

```
connect.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;" _
"Initial Catalog=reportservertempdb;Data Source=10.10.10.10;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;" _
"Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=ServerHostName;Use Encryption for Data=False;" _
"Tag with column collation when possible=False;User ID=YYDOMAIN\YYAccount;Password=YYPassword;"
```

**Scenario 1:** 'Login Failed for user YYDOMAIN\YYAccount' '80040E4D' 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server'

1. I logged in my local pc which is joined domain "yydomain.com" with my login "YYdomian\yyram"
2. Opened CMD
3. CScript.exe  and hit enter
4. getting error 'Login Failed for user YYDOMAIN\YYAccount' '80040E4D' 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server'

**Command Line Output for Scenario 1 as below:**

```
C:\Users\yyram>whoami
YYDOMAIN\yyram

C:\Users\yyram>CScript.exe "C:\Temp\Sql_Connect.vbs"
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Temp\Sql_Connect.vbs(8, 1) Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server: Login failed for user 'YYDOMAIN\YYAccount'.


C:\Users\yyram
```

**Scenario 2:** 'Login Failed for user YYDOMAIN\YYAccount' '80040E4D' 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server'

1. I logged in my local pc which is joined domain "yydomain.com" with my login "YYdomian\yyram"
2. Opened CMD 'Run As Different user' and provided details as 'User: YYDOMAIN\YYAccount & Pass: YYPassword' (FYI: using same user detail in SQL query to connect SQLDB)
3. CScript.exe  and hit enter
4. getting error 'Login Failed for user YYDOMAIN\YYAccount' '80040E4D' 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server'

**Command Line Output for Scenario 2 as below:**

```
C:\Users\yyram>whoami
YYDOMAIN\YYAccount

C:\Users\yyram>CScript.exe "C:\Temp\Sql_Connect.vbs"
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Temp\Sql_Connect.vbs(8, 1) Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server: Login failed for user 'YYDOMAIN\YYAccount'.


C:\Users\yyram>
```

**Connection string 2:** Removed "User ID=YYDOMAIN\YYAccount;Password=YYPassword;" and Added "Integrated Security=SSPI"

```
connect.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;" _
"Initial Catalog=reportservertempdb;Data Source=10.10.10.10;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;" _
"Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=ServerHostName;Use Encryption for Data=False;" _
"Tag with column collation when possible=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

**Scenario 3:** 'Login Failed for user YYDOMAIN\yyram' '80040E4D' 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server'

1. I logged in my local pc which is joined domain "yydomain.com" with my login "YYdomian\yyram"
2. Opened CMD
3. CScript.exe  and hit enter
4. getting error 'Login Failed for user YYDOMAIN\yyram' '80040E4D' 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server'

**Command Line Output for Scenario 3 as below:**

```
C:\Users\yyram>whoami
YYDOMAIN\yyram

C:\Users\yyram>CScript.exe "C:\Temp\Sql_Connect.vbs"
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Temp\Sql_Connect.vbs(8, 1) Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server: Login failed for user 'YYDOMAIN\yyram'.


C:\Users\yyram>
```

**Scenario 4:** Script execution success

1. I logged in my local pc which is joined domain "yydomain.com" with my login "YYdomian\yyram"
2. Opened CMD 'Run As Different user' and provided details as 'User: YYDOMAIN\YYAccount & Pass: YYPassword' (FYI: using same user detail in SQL query to connect SQLDB)
3. CScript.exe  and hit enter
4. Report was generated "C:\temp\test.csv" successful.

**Command Line Output for Scenario 4 as below:**

```
C:\Users\yyram>whoami
YYDOMAIN\YYAccount

C:\Users\yyram>CScript.exe "C:\Temp\Sql_Connect.vbs"
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


C:\Users\yyram>
```

So, Is there any way to provide another Windows Authentication details instead of login user details to run above VBScript?

Main VBScript code as below:

```
Dim connect, sql, resultSet, pth, txt

Set ObjFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set connect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

connect.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;" _
"User ID=YYDOMAIN\YYAccount;Password=YYPassword;Initial Catalog=reportservertempdb;Auto Translate=True;" _
"Data Source=10.10.10.10;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=ServerHostName;" _
"Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Trusted_Connection=True;"

connect.Open

sql="select sql query"

Set resultSet = connect.Execute(sql)

pth = "C:\temp\test.csv"

Set txt = ObjFSO.CreateTextFile(pth, True)

On Error Resume Next
resultSet.MoveFirst
Do While Not resultSet.eof
  txt.WriteLine(resultSet(0) & "," & resultSet(1))
  resultSet.MoveNext
Loop

resultSet.Close
connect.Close
Set connect = Nothing
```

Comment: is using the RUNAS command an option? So:        RUNAS /profile /user:YYDOMAIN\YYAccount "cScript.exe Script.vbs"             .... it is quite strange you get a SQL security error even though the proper user is defined in your ConnectionString in the script

Comment: You maybe logged in the correct account but UAC will hide that, you would need to execute the script from an elevated command prompt to get Trusted Connection to work with UAC enabled.

Comment: Hi, I am using **Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;** in _connect.ConnectionString_ , So Script sql query trying to connect server with Windows login authentication instead using username and password what i have provided in _connect.ConnectionString_ ...   So I removed **Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;** from _connect.ConnectionString_ an ran script by double click. still script failing to connect sql server with "YYDOMAIN\YYAccount".. any suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

I use two batch files.

***RUNAS_callVBSScript.cmd***

`RUNAS /savecred /user:Domain\User callVBSScript.cmd`

***callVBSScript.cmd***

`.\VBScript.vbs`

I have to enter my password on the first run and if I change my password.